# i want a error msg that the entry is already there in django forms for a particular field

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-forms

i am using model forms. in my form there is a field called `tagid`. if i entered a `tagid` in the `tagid` field and then if i submit the form. the form should not submit into the database if the entered `tagid` is already there in the database and it should tell "tag id already exists" above the tag id field.

how can i make this.

my form is

```
class InventoryItems(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = item
```

in my item table i am having a field `tagid`. so if i enter the existing `tagid` and then if i submit. it should throw a hint or text or something above  the field like"tag id already exist"

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your form:

```
    def clean_tagid(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['tagid']
        if item.objects.filter(tagid = data).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError("TagID already exists")
        return data
```